# cs-cart like upload images

Tags: file-upload

Hi i am looking for a solution for uploading images like cs-cart does in the products.

Does anyone have a suggestion

Comment: You need to be more specific about your requirements and the platform you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

Try [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/implementation/)